# Where is the .net framework error log location

Tags: .net, error-logging

My application exits for no reason, most likely due to errors in the profiler I used because it interferes with all the CLR runtime stuff. The issue is is there any file at any location where .Net framework logs these kind of errors?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As David says, these errors go to the Application Log in the Windows Event Log.

If you're looking for a bit more information as your application is terminating, you can subscribe to the [`UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event.  That way you will get an exception as your app terminates, and you can inspect the exception in the debugger, or log details to a file of your choosing, etc.

Note:  you cannot "handle" the exception in the traditional sense, your app will die.  It does however give you an opportunity to get some useful information on your way out :)

Answer (score 6):

These errors will often show up in the Windows Event Log (usually in the Application log).

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting low-level .NET issues like assembly loading and binding, you could enable .NET Fusion logging:
[How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)
Just remember to disable it when finished.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31882252)